# Why won't ruby-debug allow me to see local variables in my specs?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to use ruby-debug to debug my specs. When i do this, i am not able to access local variables. Instance variables, however, are fine. Is there a way to make this work with local variables?

Here is an example spec:

```
require 'spec/autorun'
describe "empty spec" do
  it "should be able to be debugged" do
    x = 'foo'
    @x = 'bar'
    debugger
  end
end
```

In the debugger/irb, i can see `@x` but not `x`. [Detailed output.](http://gist.github.com/238233)

Is this just a limitation of using ruby-debug with blocks or is this something I can make work for me?

(In the mean time, i'm using more instance variables than i really should in my specs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you cite is problematic with ruby-debug. ruby-debug has a limitation that it only stops at statement "line" events and the "debugger" call is the last statement of a block. Therefore in the example you give by the time the debugger stops you are no longer in the "should be able to be debugged" block and x is gone.

One workaround that programmers seem to use a bit is to put some sort of statement after "debugger" but before the end.

In the next incarnation [rbdbgr](http://wiki.github.com/rocky/rbdbgr/) (for YARV Ruby 1.9 with patches), you can stop before returning from the block.